# Having to call fetch twice from CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, core-data

Both on simulator and my real device, an array of strings is saved upon app termination. When I restart the app and fetchRequest for my persisted data (either from a viewDidLoad or a manual button action), I get an empty array on the first try. It isn't until the second time I fetchRequest that I finally get my data.

The funny thing is that there doesn't seem to be a time discrepancy involved in this issue. I tried setting various timeouts before trying to fetch the second time. It doesn't matter whether I wait 10 seconds to a minute -- or even immediately after the first fetch; the data is only fetched on the second try.

I'm having to use this code to fetch my data:

```
        var results = try self.context.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [NSManagedObject]
        while (results.isEmpty) {
            results = try self.context.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [NSManagedObject]
        }
        return results
```

For my sanity's sake, here's a checklist:

- I'm initializing the Core Data Stack using boilerplate code from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/InitializingtheCoreDataStack.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH4-SW1
- I'm putting my single DataController instance in a static variable at the top of my class `private static let context: NSManagedObjectContext = DataController().managedObjectContext`
- I'm successfully saving my context and can retrieve the items without any issue in a single session; but upon trying to fetch on the first try in a subsequent session, I get back an empty array (and there lies the issue).

Note** I forgot to mention that I'm building a framework. I am using CoreData with the framework's bundle identifier and using the model contained in the framework, so I want to avoid having to use logic outside of the framework (other than initalizing the framework in the appDelegate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That boilerplate code from Apple includes:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0)) {
    /* ... */
    do {
        try psc.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: storeURL, options: nil)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Error migrating store: \(error)")
    }
}
```

The saved data isn't available until the `addPersistentStoreWithType` call finishes, and that's happening asynchronously on a different queue. It'll finish at some point but your code above is executing before that happens. What you're seeing isn't surprising-- you're basically looping until the async call finishes.

You need to somehow delay your fetch until the persistent store has been loaded. There are a couple of possibilities:

1. Do something *sort of* like what you're already doing. I'd prefer to look at the persistent store coordinator's `persistentStores` property to see if any stores have been loaded rather than repeatedly trying to fetch.
2. Post a notification after the persistent store is loaded, and do your fetch when the notification happens.

Answer (score 2):

The Core Data stack should be initialized in applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions located in appDelegate.swift because the psc is added after you're trying to fetch your data.

Comment: One issue I have on that note (which I forgot to mention; many apologies) is that I am using CoreData in the context of a framework. I don't want my framework to be interfering with any other application's CoreData logic in the appDelegate other than for initialization in didFinishLauchingWithOptions.